# Rails Capybara XPath Feature Spec Not Seeing My Image

Tags: xpath, capybara, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using `rails 6.1`, `ruby 3.1.1` with `capybara`

I'm learning `feature specs` and I've never used `xpath` before. I have a page/view with several images that I'd like to have tests for - to be sure they are present.  The following is my first attempt on just one image:

```
# in my view:
# all images on this view are in 'app/assets/images/bars/'

<% @levels.each do |l| %>
  <% image=l.color.downcase + '-bar.png' %>
  <p><%= image_tag("bars/#{image}", id: l.color.downcase, :size => "25x50") %></p>
<% end %>
```

```
# in my feature specs

scenario "it has the level 1 image" do
 # /app/assets/images/bars/white-bar.png is level 1 image
 expect(page).to have_xpath("/img[contains( @src, 'white-bar' )]")
end
```

I've tried a couple other variations on the image path and name, but they didn't work either:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("/img[contains( @src, 'white-bar.png' )]")
expect(page).to have_xpath("/img[contains( @src, '/bars/white-bar.png' )]")
expect(page).to have_xpath("/img[contains( @src, '/images/bars/white-bar.png' )]")
```

From what I've read on xpath, "*I believe*" it is looking for an image that `contains` 'white-bar' in the name. All images on the page have unique names, so it should only see one image with `white-bar` in the name.

NOTE: when I inspect the image using developer-tools I see this:
`/assets/bars/white-bar-31c13c54bf0beaccadbdcb342490b30d380f235669ec6c31b316f6ed8100722f.png`

`/assets/bars/...` it doesn't have the `/images` in the path.

I know the long number is something added in by rails, but I don't know if it is causing any issues in the test.

Any help on explaining how this works and what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Starting a Xpath with `/` means the root.
Starting a XPath with `/img` means the root-element.
Try `//img`

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed thank you!  That worked.  `expect(page).to have_xpath("//img[contains( @src, 'white-bar' )]")`